# Right floated div within a liquid-width div. How do I get this to work?

Tags: html, css-float, css

I have a div, within the div is a name in an `<h4>` tag (it's semantically correct with the layout) and a div with some values describing that `<h4>` value. I want the nested div to be on the right side, and the only way I can get this to work is a fixed-width container and `float: right;`. As you can guess, the object breaks when the value of the `<h4>` causes the nested div move below instead of to the right. I've tried `min-width`, but it ends up stretching to the maximum size of the div containing the container div. I want it to be such that when the h4 is too big the entire div just stretches.

Comment: This is a pretty confusing question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your nested `<div>` to move down when the `<h4>` is too large, apply `clear: right` to the nested `<div>`.

Comment: I want the div to stretch, and have the nested div stay on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your h4 to display:block and floating it left.

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent div `position: relative` and the child div `position:absolute` with a small top and right value based on the margin you desire from the top-right corner of the parent div.  In order to get the expanding width behaving correctly, you should be able to set right padding on the parent div equivalent to the width of the child div so that the h4 doesn't overlap the child when it is too long, yet expands the parent div properly.

```
div { padding-right:200px; position: relative; }
div div { position: absolute; top:0; right: 0; width:200px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This work's like a charme:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="pt" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <title>Organize the Content of a DIV</title>

        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

        <style type="text/css">
            div {width:80%;}
            div h4 {float:left;max-width:40%;}
            div div {float:right;max-width:40%;}
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div>
            <h4>This is working?</h4>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Let's look at the CSS:

> 1. {width:80%;} Dynamic width for the container
> 2. h4 {float:left;max-width:40%;} Set's the  at the left of the
>      screen, and doesn't allow it to grow
>      more that 40% of the container's width
> 3. div {float:right;max-width:40%;} Set's the nested  to be on the
>      right of the screen,and doesn't allow
>      it to grow more that 40% of the
>      container's width

This is a simple way to prevent the two nested element's from breaking...
The 40% of max-width is just an example, could be 60~40 :)

Hope that helps U!